# How to set the user must login as member before purchase?

Tags: 7, commerce

How do I set the user must login as member before purchase?

I'm using Drupal version 7, with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

Comment: You can revoke permissions for anonymous user to Access Checkout in permissions page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Commerce Checkout Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) for implementing this:

> This module redirects anonymous users to a page where they can login or create a new account when they try to checkout.